# Is it possible to limit the size of parts in the linear partitioning problem?

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

I have an engineering problem that requires me to partition a set of positive numbers to k parts, without changing the ordering of the numbers in the set, so that the sums of the parts are as equal as possible. I have understood that there are solutions to this 'linear partitioning problem'. In fact, I have successfully tried the dynamic programming solution already and it works.

Now the question: What if there is a maximum size limitation for the parts? ("No part can have more than m items") Can it be added e.g. to the DP solution or can some other technique be used for solving this.

Appreciate all comments, links and suggestions.

Edit: I added a crude sketch of the original algorithm below

```
// Partition number array seq to k parts with max number of m items in each part
public void LinearPartition(double[] seq, int k, int m)
{
    double[,] table;
    int[,] solution;
    int n = seq.Length - 1;

    linearPartitionTable(seq, k, m, out table, out solution);

    k = k - 2;
    while (k >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(solution[n - 1, k] + 1);
        n = solution[n - 1, k];
        k--;
    }
}

private void linearPartitionTable(double[] seq, int k, int m, 
  out double[,] table, out int[,] solution)
{
    int n = seq.Length;

    table = new double[n, k];
    solution = new int[n - 1, k - 1];

    table[0, 0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        table[i, 0] = seq[i] + table[i - 1, 0];
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        table[0, j] = seq[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < k; j++)
        {
            double currentMin = double.MaxValue;
            int minX = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
            {
                double cost = Math.Max(table[x, j - 1], table[i, 0] - table[x, 0]);
                if (cost < currentMin)
                {
                    currentMin = cost;
                    minX = x;
                }
            }
            table[i, j] = currentMin;
            solution[i - 1, j - 1] = minX;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your implementation of the dynamic program probably has a loop where you maximize the partial objective value over all possible places to begin the last chunk so far. If so, you should be able to change the lower limit of that loop from 0 to the number of numbers so far minus the maximum.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the inner-most loop where x <- 0..i-1 ?

Comment: Yes, that's the loop.

Comment: I have tried adding the following in front of the inner-most loop:
  int minLimit = Math.Max(0, i - maxWidth);
  for (int x = minLimit; x < i; x++)
But that just does not do it. Feel so stupid to have to ask about this again...

Comment: Could you be more specific about what went wrong?